# Conflict between Android's Firebase Firestore and Places Api

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-places-api

I am using both Firebase Firestore and Places Api in my Android app. When implementing both of them in the project's build.gradle (Module: app) and then building the project, it produces DuplicateClasses error, because of protobuf and java-lite conflicts. So, I have to exclude protobuf from the implementation of one of them like this:

```
implementation('com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.3.0', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-lite'
})
```

but, doing this produces errors while the app is running like: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.zzdv` and then the app shuts down.

What could be done to solve this issue?

I was thinking that excluding the whole group `exclude group: 'com.google.protobuf', module: 'protobuf-lite'` is too general. So, it'd be better if I could find the duplicate classes and exclude them and **only** them. However, I do not know how to find these classes or if it actually works like this.

It would be really appreciated if you could help me out on this or suggest ways that I can deal with this issue. Thank you.

Edit:

Without the `exclude` statement, it gives build errors. Here are the logs as requested:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteOutput found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ArraysByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$BoundedByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LeafByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$SystemByteArrayCopier found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$AbstractBufferedEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ArrayEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ByteOutputEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutOfSpaceException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DoubleArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExperimentalApi found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryFactory found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite$ObjectIntPair found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$FieldDescriptorLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FloatArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$DefaultInstanceBasedParser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage$ExtensionWriter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessageOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtensionDescriptor found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$GeneratedExtension found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.IntArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$BooleanList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$DoubleList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLiteMap found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$FloatList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$IntList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter$Converter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$LongList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$Converter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$EntryAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$IteratorAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$SetAdapter found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ProtobufList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyEntry found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyFieldLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteArrayListView found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteStringListView found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LongArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$Metadata found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapFieldLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteToString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MutabilityOracle$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.NioByteString$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Parser found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ProtobufArrayList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ProtocolStringList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$Balancer found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$PieceIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.RopeByteString$RopeInputStream found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EmptySet found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EmptySet$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EmptySet$2 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$Entry found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EntryIterator found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.SmallSortedMap$EntrySet found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$2 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$ByteSequence found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSetLite found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$1 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$2 found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil found in modules jetified-protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and jetified-protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
```

(I could not post all the lines as stackoverflow limits the body to 30000 characters)

Comment: can you post the exact log without exclude code

Comment: @BurhanKhanzada I have just updated the question

Comment: @osama-salmaa Could you please share your gradle file?

Comment: @AmjadTubasi I found the solution to the problem, I just posted it in the comments. Thank you so much for trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution. It might not be optimal, but it works.

In my gradle file, I'm implementing those two:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
```

Firebase have upgraded their libraries to protobuf-javalite, while Google's PlacesApi haven't. So, I just downgraded Firebase-Firestore's version to `21.4.3`, and everything works fine 'till the moment.